# Mako, Jinja2, Won't Install In Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, installation, jinja2, cherrypy, mako

I'm trying to install some template languages to use with CherryPy & Python3, but they won't install. Mako & Jinja2 both install fine into Python 2, but when I try installing them for Py3, they produce errors and won't install. They give this same error:

```
TypeError: can't use a bytes pattern on a string-like object
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, Python 3.2.3, and tried installing Mako 0.7.2 and Jinja2. Any idea if there's a way to install them? If not, is there a good template language that IS useful in CherryPy w/ Py3?

**Update**: Here's the entire Traceback for the error when I try `sudo python3 setup.py install`

```
Adding Mako 0.7.2 to easy-install.pth file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 61, in <module>
    **extra
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py", line 917, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/distutils/dist.py", line 936, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.13-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 73, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.13-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 101, in do_egg_install
    cmd.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.13-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 342, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.13-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 562, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(None, spec, tmpdir, deps, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.13-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 613, in install_item
    self.process_distribution(spec, dist, deps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.13-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 641, in process_distribution
    self.install_egg_scripts(dist)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.13-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 511, in install_egg_scripts
    dist.get_metadata('scripts/'+script_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.13-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 735, in install_script
    script_text = get_script_header(script_text) + (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.13-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1588, in get_script_header
    match = first_line_re.match(first)
TypeError: can't use a bytes pattern on a string-like object
```

Comment: How are you installing them, and what triggers that error? I recall getting Jinja2 to work with Python 3.

Comment: I got Jinja2 (Jinja2-2.6/) working with Python 3.2.  You get that error when installing the Mako or Jinja2?

Comment: I'm installing them via the commandline, like `sudo python3 distribute_setup.py install` kinda thing. I get the error from both mako & Jinja2. I'm a bit of a python newbie tho I've been learning it for a few months now, so I'm guessing I'm doing something a little bit wrong... just don't know what.

Answer (score 2):

Look on `http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/xenwebmanager/wiki/GettingStarted`  for pythion and Cherrypy .
For Joomla look on `http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/intro/`

This is install on terminal

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
easy_install Jinja2
pip install Jinja2

http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/02/how-install-pip-ubuntu/
```